# CORS and createPayment Errors for PayPal Standard

Tags: post, woocommerce, paypal, cors

Summary is failure to complete payments with 'PayPal Standard' from woocommerce wordpress site. CORS error shows on paypal sign-in page from checkout and createPayment error appears after clicking 'pay now' using all payment methods, cards, stored balance etc. Paypal said they have not blocked anything their side and it all works fine in sandbox mode.

I started with paypal for woocommerce plugin and then Angelleye's plugin for using Paypal Express checkout, those both gave the same error 10417 after clicking pay now which basically says there is no usable funding source for the account try a different payment method. This same error happens for positive paypal balance as well as debit/credit cards. The personal payer account is well established and works fine elsewhere. Both work in sandbox mode.

So I downgraded to PayPal Standard to pass more onto paypal (also works fine in sandbox). When I click proceed to PayPal on checkout I get this appear in Chrome and Edge browsers when landing on the sign in page:

hermes?country.x=AE&…useraction=commit:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/xo/hermes/1.9.0/framework-code-split.js' from origin 'https://www.paypal.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

If I click on the hermes? link the red cross in console is on the first line !DOCTYPE html

Proceeding to login ok, selecting a payment method and pressing 'pay now' I then get the following error shown in the console and the paypal page just refreshes once to the same paynow button state, ie unchanged

xhr-ads.min.js:formatted:703 POST https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/checkout/82T95103LS393105S/session/createPayment 400

Clicking the xhr link the red cross for failed to load resource is on the line beginning n.send:

```
c.send = function() {
        !c.xRequestWithHeaderSet && c.isPayPalRequest && 
c.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"),
        n.send.apply(n, arguments),
        c.xRequestWithHeaderSet = !1
```

Clicking on the https link in the error highlights createPayment as the xhr problem in red which shows:

```
{ack: "contingency", contingency: "PAYER_CANNOT_PAY", errorData: {}, meta: 
{calc: "3791667e34426",…},…}
ack: "contingency"
contingency: "PAYER_CANNOT_PAY"
errorData: {}
```

Pay pal say they have no issue with the payments attempted and have not blocked anything on the buyer account and the fact I get the same result on a positive preloaded balance payment as I do for cards that must rule out the banks having an issue, authorisation also seemingly returns success in the xhr list before createPayment error. They just said try a different device.

Have been trying to solve this for a couple of weeks and could really do with some help. I have asked merchant technical support but it's hit and miss on whether ever hear back from paypal support.

Is the first CORS error related to the payment failure do you think? Thanks

Edit note: Someone posted similar 2 days ago here https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1070

Comment: Hello, Yes on Edge too it gives SEC7128: [CORS] The origin 'https://www.paypal.com' found multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin response headers for cross-origin  resource at 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/xo/hermes/1.9.0/framework-code-split.js'. and then on payment Edge gives: HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
(XHR)POST - https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/checkout/6X7519785X452403K/session/createPayment . I disabled WProcket which was the only thing I thought might affect headers but it didn't change the outcomes.

Comment: So yeah the problem is that `https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/xo/hermes/1.9.0/framework-code-split.js` is misconfigured. It is sending two `access-control-allow-origin: *` response headers in the response. That’s exactly the cause of the error the browser is reporting. So if you’re in contact with somebody from PayPal, you should let them know that server is misconfigured.

Comment: Just saw your reply on github and wondered if was something only paypal could alter, it's clear here. I spent past couple of days trying to influence my own CORS settings. Thanks for clearing up whose side it is coming from.

Comment: @edindubai I'm also having the same issues. I just read on github that paypal has rolled out a fix, but its still not working for me, and as it seems some others also still complain on github .. but the issue has been closed as for now. I hope they will reopen it since its not fixed. `https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1070`

Comment: @edindubai oh I just realized that you are actually in the comments on github :D than you already know. Cheers !

Comment: So papal merchant support say their engineers say their CORS error is not the cause (pun intended) of the payment failure but they are unsure what is. I pointed out that the push to fix the CORS error didn't fix that anyway, perhaps they thought it did. I see they closed your new ticket about it too @b101. :/